# Excel format lost while populating thru SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, formatting

I have an formatted excel destination with one of the columns being a percentage and another being currency. I'm loading this excel with data from a sql table using SSIS. However the excel is not formatted after the load. What is happening?

Comment: Your question is missing some critical points of detail: SQL Server version, Excel file format version, and steps you are applying.

Answer (score 0):

I was able export two columns of information (percent and dollar value) to an Excel file (97-2003 format) from an SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2010.  The data was sourced from a table on a server using SQL Server 2012.

Steps:

1. Created an Excel file containing a column called Percent and another called Cost.  Both were formatted accordingly and are located in the first row.
2. Saved the file in a 97-2003 format and then closed it.
3. Created a table in a database and populated it with a couple of records.

```
    create table test_export (
        mypercent numeric(18,2),
        mydollar numeric(18,2))
```

`insert into test_export values (2.1, 50.00)
    insert into test_export values (4.5, 120.00)`

4. Opened Visual Studio 2010 and created a new SSIS package.  Created an OLEDB connection to the database.
5. Under the Control Flow tab added a Data Flow Task and double-clicked on it after it was added.  This should now highlight the Data Flow tab.
6. Add an OLE DB Source and point to the newly added database connection, under Data access mode select Table or View and then select the table created in step #3.  Select the OK button.
7. Add an Excel Destination making certain to create a new Excel connection manager for it and point to the Sheet1$.  Make certain to indicate that the first row contains headers.  Select the OK button and connect the OLE DB Source task to the Excel Destination task below.  Since only numbers are involved, there is no need to apply a Data Conversion task between the two.  But in the Excel Destination task remember to select Mappings and connect from left to right which source columns match up with which destination columns.
8. In the Solution Explorer pane, right-click on the solution and select Properties from the drop-down menu.   Open Configuration Properties on the left and the select Debugging under it.  On the right under Debug Options, look for Run64BitRuntime and change it from True to False if you have not already done so.  Select the OK button.
9. Run the SSIS package.
10. Stop the SSIS package when all of the tasks show green for completed.
11. Open the Excel file and it will now contain the values imported from the database table with the Excel percent and dollar formats preserved from step #1.

I ran these steps in a test and everything worked perfectly.  If your formats are not being preserved, then you are likely leaving out a step.

Hope this helps and please indicate if it answered your question.

Comment: Super old question, but the problem I have arises when a row has no data for a specific column - causing all subsequent rows to lose formatting. If I have 10 rows and the 5th one does not have a value, then rows 6-10 lose any formatting (border, alignment, data format) that the previous rows have.

Comment: It has been nearly three years and the critical details you just articulated a couple of hours ago were not included in the original question.  I hope you have since figured out the problem. If not, just apply the derived column workaround in the data control to check for NULL's.  Take a look at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840909/how-do-i-change-null-values-to-empty-strings?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks, that looks really helpful. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was:

1. apply conditional formatting on the column.
   [see attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPmV.png)
2. It is also important that you have in the first row, a model row, filled with numeric/text values, in order for the ssis to export the numbers as numbers and not as strings [model row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0FTv.png)

If your template contains several rows before the place where ssis start to export the data, you might need to have more model rows. (I needed 4). This rows have to be the first rows in the document, regardless where you start the export.

3. You can hide the model rows